# Google Cloud Function vs Run vs App Engine for stateless latex render?

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-run

I have been away from developing cloud based application for years and now I am confused by the many many options.

I need to cloud provider (Google?) to fire up a virtual machine/container/process in response to a HTTP API call.

That container will contain a full LaTeX distribution. It will be provided input (document, diagrams) and it will run the latex compiler to create a PDF which is returned as output back to the API caller.

The service is stateless - between each call nothing needs to be remembered.

For optimising such a heavy and slow process, it would be nice to have

- a configurable number of warm containers ready to take calls, but reducible down to zero for cost reasons, "scale to zero"
- persist container to take multiple calls, and only kill the container if there is a long pause in API requests
- ability to pull the latex application into RAM to minimise startup time which is known to be long

And also

- to reduce passing document and images over the API call, it would be better for the call to refer to a storage location which the instance could connect to and pull the input data from (and maybe write the rendered PDF back to)

I know I can do this with a general purpose Google App Engine, but I don't know enough about Google Cloud Function and Cloud Run. My understanding is the Cloud Function can't run arbitrary applications like LaTeX, only supplied code snippets that match the provides runtimes (java, js, python, go..)

Comment: Have you containerized your application? Have you benchmarked your app's requirements for CPU, memory, storage, and I/O? A good recommendation requires more details on your application's requirements. Suggestion: I think Cloud Run will meet your needs based on your listed requirements and goals.

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually looking for exactly the same thing. I want to send HTTP requests together with the .tex content to a back-end service. This back-end service should build (and store) the LaTeX pdf file online and return the URL of the created PDF file.

I think Google Cloud Run (GCR) is suitable for this, but i haven't managed to properly dockerize this. First you need to install the LaTeX distribution inside the container and somehow you have to build an HTTP API server to handle incoming requests. It would be advisable to connect GCR with Google Cloud Storage (GCS) for storing the pdf and all pictures, ... you want to include inside the pdf. Storing them once seems like a far better method then sending them along with every HTTP request.

I already have some experience with GCR, GCS and Cloud functions from another project of mine. However I haven't managed to get the LaTeX online compiler service working.

Maybe we can work together and try to get this up and running?